# Good way to distribute compiled files for testers

Tags: testing, version-control

What would be a good way to distribute compiled code to testers for quality inssurance ?  Like dll's or .fas files for AutoLISP.

So far it's included in the source control which is bad practice and hard to maintain. We would like to avoid giving access to code to our testers.

Comment: For me, you have to post this question in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a repository like Artifactory. Your build can publish the artifacts to Artifactory and you can give testers access to Artifactory but not to your codebase.

**But if they are writing automated tests, this is an antipattern IMO. Tests should be stored alongside the code in the same repository.**